# Disconnected graphs.

Tags: graph-theory, model-theory, first-order-logic

A question asked before 
 ([There exists no zero-order or first-order theory for connected graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991644/there-exists-no-zero-order-or-first-order-theory-for-connected-graphs)) proved that no theory exists such that axiomtizes *connected* graphs.

Using the same type of argument (Compactness theorem for first order logic), is it possible to prove the disconnected graphs are axiomtizable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There exists no zero-order or first-order theory for connected graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991644/there-exists-no-zero-order-or-first-order-theory-for-connected-graphs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no theory in the language of graphs whose models are exactly the disconnected (by which I assume you mean "not connected") graphs. It is possible to prove this fact simultaneously with the fact that there is no theory of connected graphs: the problem is that we can build graphs that are elementarily equivalent (i.e., have the same theory), but where one is connected and the other disconnected.

Let $G_0$ be the graph whose vertices are the integers, with edges between adjacent integers. Let $L$ be the language of graphs, and $T$ the complete theory of $G_0$ as an $L$ structure. Let $L'$ be $L$ together with two new constant symbols, and let $T'$ be $T$ together with an axiom schema asserting that there is no path of length $n$ connecting the two constant symbols, for any $n$. $T'$ is finitely consistent, using $G_0$ as the graph and interpreting the constant symbols as integers that are sufficiently far apart. By compactness, $T'$ has a model. That model will be a graph $G_1$ that is elementarily equivalent to $G_0$ in the graph language, but the new constant symbols from $L'$ must be interpreted as vertices in different connected components.

So we have $G_0$ elementarily equivalent to $G_1$, with $G_0$ connected and $G_1$ disconnected, so you can't tell whether a graph is connected by looking at its theory. Consequently, you can't axiomatize either "connected graphs" or "disconnected graphs" (in the language of graphs).

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer! 
I understand everything up to "By compactness, T' has a model", but I am confused about how we derive graph G_1. By construction G_0 is connected. Do we not need to construct another graph G_1 to use in our proof, or can we just state that G_0 and G_1 are elementarily equivalent?

Comment: @Minnee The overall sketch of my construction in paragraph two is 1) build a theory $T'$, 2) Show it is finitely consistent, 3) Use compactness to conclude it is consistent, 4) The definition of consistent means that $T'$ has a model. Call that model $G_1$. Compactness is letting us do something very sneaky, here: when we're showing that $T'$ is finitely consistent, the model for every finite part of $T'$ is just going to be the graph $G_0$ and the work is finding interpretations for the constants. But the graph we get from step 4 is not isomorphic to $G_0$.

Comment: @Minnee If you've seen the classic compactness proof that there is a model of the theory of $\mathbb{R}$ with an infinite element, it's very similar to what's happening there.

Comment: I see! So the final step is stating G_1 is disconnected, but as T is the theory whose models are connected graphs, we arrive at a contradiction?

Comment: @Minnee The way I framed it, $T$ was just the complete theory of $G_0$ in the graph language, and the contradiction is that, if a class of structures is axiomatizable, you can't have a structure in the class model the exact same sentences as one not in the class. I'm pretty tired; sorry if I'm not being very clear.